# How can i get a refresh token using Salesforce OAuth?

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am trying to get a refresh token , I call the following in c#

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var client = new RestClient(serviceUrl + "/token");
        var request = new RestRequest("", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("refresh_token", refreshtoken, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("client_id", clientId, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        request.AddParameter("client_secret", clientSecret, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

but constantly get the error:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"expired access/refresh token"}
```

I have in the Connected App in Salesforce set "Refresh token is valid until revoked"

Any ideas on how i can fix this ?

Comment: See following : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: when you say see following, its a huge repository, I have looked and followed these examples, specifically for refresh token. Im asking if anyone has come across this and can point in the right direction or has a some sort of resolution.

Comment: First you should not be using TLS11.  Only TLS12 and TLS13.  Your error says that the token is expired.  So you need to get new token.  See at link : Request an Access Token

Comment: that goes through the callback and re-authenticating to SF. I am using this to run a scheduled task and it seems to expire after 4hours

Comment: the token says it expired 3/20  , so i should be able to get a new access token by using the refresh token ?

Comment: The link says following : Token obtained from the web server, user-agent, or hybrid app token flow. This value is a secret. Take appropriate measures to protect it.

This parameter is returned only if your connected app is set up with a refresh_token scope.  See following : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_hybrid_app_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: For TLS, the following may be of interest: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls).

Comment: I have looked and tried those , same error